# Why is angular .css method not detecting media query changes

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, media-queries

*NOTE: in this example I am using 'height', but I will be querying other css properties also.*

---

I have media queries that are setting an element's height.

I have an angular directive that watches that height.

The height changes when window is resized (manually), and the watch function is called (via .digest()), but the .css('height') is empty.

```
  return element.css("height") ; // --> nothing
```

please see my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iWkEzE0w61UbHj7v3BMM?p=preview).

Comment: I haven't answered why but i made it working if you like it give me upvote and accept as ans otherwise i will remove my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to answer your question

```
instead of this element.css("height");
```

Try using below code

```
element[0].offsetHeight
```

Check the updated plunker code
http://plnkr.co/edit/PdaVBjutGeEn7csNm1ki?p=preview

Comment: thanks ... I did not mention in my question that I am not necessarily interested in `height`, per-se. I just used height for my example ... ... however, you did get it to work, as per my example ... +1